# SVG viewBox="0 0 100 100" wont scale my path to 100%?

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, path, viewbox

I currently have an svg path that only shows about 50%. How can I get it to show 100%?
Here is my code:

```
<div className="svgPathContainer">
   <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
     <path d="M82 88L0 0H123V170H0L82 88Z" fill="#F9B300" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

I have  className="svgPath" set as:

```
.svgPathContainer{ 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Here is also an example of the svg only showing at 50%:
https://codesandbox.io/s/svg-scaling-fff1q?file=/src/App.js:93-357

**The problem:** Why wont the svg path scale to 100% of the .svgPathContainer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `viewBox` is like a canvas size. So drawings outside of this view box will be clipped. Like css overflow: hidden. And your drawing has a size of width 123px and height 170px. So you have to change the view box to this value. Check our some [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox).

If you want to keep the viewbox of 100 x 100 px, you need to change your drawing element size (path).

The view box has nothing to do with the scale. It's just the canvas size. A rect clip with width, height and offset (x y w h) for the SVG elements inside. And the SVG tag's width and height attributes are for scale the rendered image.

```html
<div className="svgPathContainer">
   <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewbox="0 0 123 170" preserveAspectRatio="none">
     <path d="M82 88L0 0H123V170H0L82 88Z" fill="#F9B300" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Your comment "The view box has nothing to do with the scale. It's just the canvas size" helped me understand. Thank you